# IAd banner moves entire skscene upwards

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

I put an ad banner in my spritekit game and when an ad shows up, the banner shoves the entire screen upwards. I tried changing the zposition of the banner but that did nothing.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var adBanner: ADBannerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skview = view as! SKView
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
          //  skview.showsPhysics = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBanner?.delegate = self
        self.adBanner?.hidden = true


        //adBannerView?.hidden = true
        skview.presentScene(scene)
    }
    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.adBanner?.hidden = false
    }
    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.adBanner.layer.zPosition = 2
    }
    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.adBanner?.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: 1)  abandon using iAd, they are not accepting new iAd apps. 2) if you are adding it via the UI  Builder then you need to make sure it is a subview that hovers over it, and not attached to the top of it with the skiver being a child of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two iAd banners. One you've created with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and one you've created in Interface Builder. Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`.